# Rudin's PMA Definition 7.14

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin's statement is as follows:

**Definition 7.14**

If $X$ is a metric space, $\phi(X)$ will denote the set of all complex-valued, continuous, bounded functions with domain $X$.

[Note that boundedness is redundant if $X$ is compact (Theorem 4.15).]

**Theorem 4.15**

If $f$ is a continuous mapping of a compact metric space $X$ into $R^k$, then $f(X)$ is closed and bounded. Thus, $f$ is bounded.

This follows from Theorem 2.41

**Theorem 2.41**

If a set $E$ in $R^k$ has one of the following three properties, then it has the other two:

(a) $E$ is closed and bounded.

(b) $E$ is compact.

(c) Every infinte subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.

**Remarks 1.38**

$R^2$ is called the plane, or the complex plane (compare Definition 1.24 and 1.36).

My question is as follows:

$1$.Rudin means that we choose $k=2$ in Theorem and apply it to def 7.14, but is it scrupulous? I mean maybe some specific properties of complex number which $R^2$ doesn't have may influnce the conclusion, but in fact I think it doesn't influnce in this situation.

$2$.what's the remarks 1.38 means? $R^2$ sometimes be complex plane or $R^2$ is the complex plane? I think it means $R^2$ sometimes be complex plane, and the properties $R^2$ has are all inclued in complex plane.

Comment: The map $(a,b) \mapsto a + bi$ is an *isometry* (that is, a distance-preserving bijection) between the metric spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Two metric spaces are essentially indistinguishable from a topological point of view when an isometry exists between them.

Comment: @Menander I Thanks. I don't know isometry.